# Python logging overhead

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm writing my code using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) module with a lot of info/debug logging (**logging.FileHandler**). I'm concerned that extensive using of logging in **asyncio** will decrease the performance of my application, because logging is blocking operation.

What is the best solution for that? Didn't find any information on logging overhead.

Maybe using [SocketHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#sockethandler) or [MemoryHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler) will help? For metrics I'm using [statsd](https://docs.atlassian.com/aiostats/latest/_modules/aiostats.html) (which is also blocking operation, but must be very fast), but I'm more concerned with non-blocking logging.

Code example:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def creator_worker(self):
    while not self.q.empty():
        with (yield from self.semaphore):
            sample = yield from self.q.get()
            logging.debug('Got new sample, processing')
            # start processing
```

I'm aware of

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG'] = '1'
import asyncio
```

But that's not what I'm looking for.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Logging document provided a solution, log through a QueueHandler, then use a QueueListener to handle log record in another thread.
https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging-cookbook.html#dealing-with-handlers-that-block

Answer (score 3):

You may create a custom log handler.
The handler will push logging record into a queue.
Another thread may read data from the queue and perform actual logging.

As an option you may use `SysLogHandler` -- it's pretty fast.
But, anyway, logging too much reduces performance, you can do nothing with it.